# PJSIP/PJSUA - Python - Check registration status

Tags: python, sip, voip, pjsip

Following *registration.py* and *call.py* examples [here](http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/browser/pjproject/trunk/pjsip-apps/src/python/samples?rev=2171) I have developed my SIP client that works quite well.

Unfortunately, if the SIP server restarts the client thinks it is still registered, the server doesn't have it registered anymore and therefore the client does not receive calls.

I tried checking in a while loop the `acc.info().reg_status` but it always report "200" (OK)...

How would you make the client continuously check if it is actually registered and if not run the registration again?

Thank you,

dk

---

This is the registration code:

```
# Register to SIP server
acc = lib.create_account(pj.AccountConfig(sip_server, sip_user, sip_password))
acc_cb = MyAccountCallback(acc)
acc.set_callback(acc_cb)
acc_cb.wait()
print "Registration complete [server: %s, user: %s]: status: %s (%s)" % (sip_server, sip_user, acc.info().reg_status, acc.info().reg_reason)
my_sip_uri = "sip:" + transport.info().host + ":" + str(transport.info().port)
print my_sip_uri
```

Comment: I think acc.info().reg_status shows the right code (200). It doesn't update if something is wrong with the server. One idea is to REGISTER each 30seconds (if a previous record exist, it will be replaced), but in general you must follow the timeout value

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes I was thinking about re-REGISTER on a regular basis, but there should be a way where the client realize that is disconnected. What is the timeout value to which you are referring to?

Comment: I'm talking about "Expires" header field of a REGISTER message

Comment: ok you mean the `reg_expires` value? I tried to modify it but it seems not working.. and wondering if once expired a REGISTER is sent again... Any ideas on that?

Comment: I wonder why after your sip server restarts forgot about previously registered address, it shouldn't act like that. As far as I know registrar servers have a database where they store UAC (client) address.

Comment: well modifying 'expires' field won't help in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default pjsip sends re-registration request after every 600s.I mean the keep-alive timeout is 600s by default.So you can change it as you want.Change it for a different value.Here is a sample...

```
acc_cfg.ka_interval =30;
```

Comment: Thanks, so this means that every 30s it will in do a REGISTER by itself automatically?

Comment: Thank you, I have found the parameter and from the description [link](http://www.pjsip.org/python/pjsua.htm#AccountConfig) the default value `ka_interval = 15`. Actually sniffing the traffic there is one UDP packet that is sent each 15 seconds to port 5060 of the server `Data: 0d0a` I guess is some sort of heart beat.